# Правописание наречия с приставкой "по-", образованного от имени собственного

Tags: орфография, прописная-строчная, наречия, приставка

["Эта Сашина забывчивость меня доконает... Пожалуйста, сделай это, но только ***не по-сашиному,*** без отсрочек и оговорок".](http://magazines.russ.ru/october/2006/7/ep12-pr.html)

Где это правило можно найти?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это есть у Лопатина:

http://orthographia.ru/orfograf_uk.php?oid=5227

Заглавная буква имени сохраняется в случаях исходного притяжательного прилагательного на **-ин** (Вас**ин**о - **по-Васиному**).